# Show that the mapping is one to one iff $|f(S)|=|S|$, and the two definitions for being onto are equivalent.

Tags: functions

Definition: $f(X)=${$f(x)|x\in X$}, "$|A|$"represents the number of elements in the set A.

In the title, $f:S\to T$, "$iff$" means "if and only if".$S$and $T$ are finite sets.
Two definitions for being onto: 

1.If for every element $ t$ in $T$, there exists some $s\in S$, such that $f(s)=t$, then it's onto.

2.$f(S)=T$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saying, about a function $f\colon S\to T$,

> for every $t\in T$ there exists $s\in S$ such that $f(s)=t$

or

> $f(S)=T$

is exactly the same, because, by definition,
$$
f(S)=\{t\in T: \text{there exists $s\in S$ such that $f(s)=t$}\}.
$$

Now, when $S$ is finite, saying $|f(S)|=|S|$ is equivalent to $f$ being one-to-one.

($\Leftarrow$) If $f$ is one-to-one, it defines a bijection $f'\colon S\to S$, so $|f(S)|=|S|$ by definition of having the same cardinality. (Note that this doesn't require $S$ is finite.)

($\Rightarrow$) Suppose $|f(S)|=|S|$ and that $f(s_1)=f(s_2)$, with $s_2\ne s_1$; set $S'=S\setminus\{s_2\}$; then $f(S')=f(S)$. Now, for *every* function $g\colon X\to Y$, $|g(X)|\le |X|$ (why?), so
$$
|S|=|f(S)|=|f(S')|\le|S'|=|S|-1
$$
which is absurd.

Comment: by definition: f(S) should be {f(s)|$s\in S$}

Comment: $S'=S\setminus\{s_2\}$, what do you mean by that? the notation is hard to follow

Answer (score 0):

To show that the two definitions for being onto is equivalent:

1. If for $\forall t\in T$, $\exists s\in S|f(s)=t$, then $T\subseteq f(S)$, and for $\forall a\in f(S), a\in T$,so $f(S)\subseteq T$. Therefore $f(S)=T$

2. If $T=f(S)$, then for $\forall t\in T,t=f(s)$ for some $s\in S$.

To show that $f$ is one to one iff $|f(S)|=|S|$:

1.when  $f$ is one to one, for $\forall s\in S$, $f(s)$ is distinct, therefore there do not exist $f(s_1)=f(s_2)|s_1\neq s_2$. Thus if $|S|=n$, there are n distinct elements in $f(S)$, therefore$|f(S)|=|S|$.

2.If $|f(S)|=|S|,|S|=n$, assume that $\exists f(s_1)=f(s_2)|s_1\neq s_2$. Then for $n$ representations of elements in $f(S)$, some of them are equal, and therefore $|f(S)|<n=|S|$, a contradiciton. Therefore for $\forall s_1,s_2,f(s_1)\neq f(s_2)$, thus $f$ is one to one.

Answer (score 0):

$f(S)=T\Leftrightarrow f\text{ is onto.}$ This is the very definition for "onto".

We'll show now that if $|f(S)=|S|$, then $f$ is one to one. This is obvious if $|S|=1$, so suppose $|S|\geq2$. If $|f(S)|=|S|=m$, and $f(x)=f(y)$ for some $x,y\in S$, consider the set $S_x=S-\{x\}$. It has $m-1$ elements. If $x\neq y$, $f(S_x)$ has $m$ elements, since it still contains the element $f(x)=f(y)$. But the image of a set of $m$ elements cannot have more than $m$ elements, hence we have a contradiction, so $x=y$ and we conclude that $f$ is one to one.

Suppose now that $f$ is one to one, and that $|f(S)|\neq |S|$. Since the image of a set cannot have more elements than this set, we have $|f(S)|<|S|$. WLOG, we can suppose that $S=\{1,\ldots,m\}$. For each $j\leq m$ consider the set $S_j=f(\{1,\ldots,j\})$. Let be $k$ the least integer such that $|f(S_k)|<k$ and $|f(S_{k-1})|=k-1$. Hence, $f(k)\in f(S_{k-1})$, so $f$ is not one to one, a contradiction.